# How to move a Cut Loop and Slide using a measure

Tags: edit-mode, edges, loop

Im using centimeters as unit of length and I've created a plane.

Now I want to make a edge loop and place it at 6cm from the left edge of the plane.

I went in `Edit Mode`, pressed `CMD+R` placed the *Edge Loop* at the left edge of the place `LEFT CLICK`, pressed `G` entered `Y` inserted `6` but nothing, the *Edge Loop* is not moving.

What I'm doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the *Edge Loop* and place it as you did before. Without deselecting it, press <kbd>N</kbd> to bring up the sidebar and select the *Item* tab. Here, you can view and edit the exact location of the selected loop cut. Just click on the X, Y or Z values.

An easy method to get an exact value from the left edge is to snap the loop cut onto the left edge of the plane (before left-clicking to apply the loop cut). Then, apply the loop cut and add 6cm to the Y value in the sidebar.

Comment: Thanks, both methods work great!